# Changing Like Button Color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to change the icon shape and color of the IconButton when it is pressed but there is nothing happens.  here is my code:

```
 String adTitle = widget.documentSnapshot['Title'];
String $adDescription = widget.documentSnapshot['Description'];

IconData _iconData = Icons.favorite_border_outlined;
Color _iconColor = Colors.red;

return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [ 
      Row(
        children: [
          IconButton.outlined(
            icon: Icon(
              _iconData,
              size: 40,
              color: _iconColor,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _iconData = Icons.favorite;
                _iconColor = Colors.blue;
              });
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: I think your code should work if you initialize `IconData _iconData = Icons.favorite_border_outlined;` and `Color _iconColor = Colors.red;` outside the `build()` method.

Comment: You are right.. it worked when I put it outside the class .. Thank you @MiftakhulArzak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IconData _iconData = Icons.favorite_border_outlined;
Color _iconColor = Colors.red;
```

They are local variables as of now. You need to make them class level varibales for this to work (define them outside build method)